# onclick event - how to change the bottom border of a button after an onclick event?

Tags: javascript, dom

```
let btn = [...document.querySelectorAll(".box__btn-resp")];
btn.forEach((e, i) => {if (e[i].onclick) {
e[i].style.borderBottom = "solid blue";});
```

I'm doing a quiz, and I'd like when the player clicks on one of the four options, it has a blue bottom border.  I tried iterating through the elements with forEach, as you can see in the code above, but it didn't work that way. I could do this with addeventlistener, but it would be very repetitive. However, I'm not sure how to get it to work any other way.  Does anyone know how to do this without getting repetitive? Thanks if you can help. I'm using Google Translate, so I'm sorry if there are any mistakes

Answer (score 0):

Why repetitive?

```js
const btns = [...document.querySelectorAll(".box__btn-resp")];
btns.forEach(btn => btn.onclick = e => {
  btns.forEach(_btn => _btn.style.borderBottom = "1px solid #333")
  e.target.style.borderBottom = "solid blue"
})
```

```html
<button class="box__btn-resp">Click</button>
<button class="box__btn-resp">Click</button>
<button class="box__btn-resp">Click</button>
<button class="box__btn-resp">Click</button>
<button class="box__btn-resp">Click</button>
```

Comment: Man, this was the answer I was looking for.  Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: You are welcome, mark as solved if it solved your issues.

Answer (score -1):

Hello is this what you are looking for? This will take the button that is clicked and add a bottom border.

Single

```js
var elem = document.getElementById("btn");
elem.addEventListener('click', function()
{
  elem.style.borderBottom = "thick solid #0000FF";
});
```

```html
<button id="btn">hello</button>
```

Multiple

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
for(var x=0; x<elements.length; x++)
{
  elements[x].addEventListener('click', function()
  {
    for(var z=0; z<elements.length; z++)
    {
      elements[z].style.borderBottom = "thick solid #0000FF";
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<button>Item 1</button>
<button>Item 2</button>
<button>Item 3</button>
<button>Item 4</button>
```

Comment: Yes, it's something like that first option I'm looking for, but without using an addEventListener, so it doesn't get repetitive.